# Specflow BeforeTestRun Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, bdd, specflow

```
[BeforeFeature]
public static void BeforeFeature()
{

    featureTitle = $"{FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title}";
    featureRollFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender
    {
        AppendToFile = true,
        StaticLogFileName = true,
        Threshold = Level.All,
        Name = "FeatureAppender",
        File = "test.log",
        Layout = new PatternLayout("%date %m%newline%exception"),
    };
    featureRollFileAppender.ActivateOptions();
    log.Info("test");
```

}

I am attempting to use log4net to output a simple string, however, once the file has been generated, it does not contain any data.
No errors are thrown and the test does complete successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the previously selected RollingFileAppender was still open and I needed to select another RollingFileAppender. This is one of the issues when using multiple log files. Once this was resolved, the Info() method would output to my desired log file.

I was able to resolve my issue by adding the following code:

```
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(nameRunRollFileAppender);
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Tracer));
        log.Info("Output some data");
```